# Is there an easy way on GitHub.com to find a repository's creation date?

Tags: github

Is there a easy way on GitHub.com to find a repositories creation date?  I'm comparing a number of projects and would rather not check each of them out if possible.

Comment: What do you define as a repository's "creation date"? The authored date of the first commit in the repository? When the repository was first pushed to GitHub?

Comment: Also, what, to you, is considered "easy"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the created date of a repository project on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611669/how-to-find-the-created-date-of-a-repository-project-on-github)

Comment: The fact that Github makes this information obscure enough to warrant several SO questions and answers is IMO pretty ridiculous.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If, by "creation date", you mean when a repo was first created ***on GitHub*** by either using `New Repo` or forking a repo, then you can get that information through the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get):

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo> | grep created_at

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4944  100  4944    0     0   8337      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8337

  "created_at": "2014-04-21T05:03:30Z",
```

The command above assumes that you have access to the `curl` and `grep` tools from the command-line. If you're using Windows, an equivalent to `grep` is `findstr`.

Notice the `created_at` date-time stamp. It's in UTC (that's what the `Z` means), and it says that the repo was created on GitHub on April 21<sup>st</sup>, 2014, at 05:03:30 UTC.

Also note that this is ***not the same as the author and committer dates of the initial commit***. To get those, simply use `git log` for the repo in question:

```
git log --reverse --format=fuller
```

Comment: Curl and grep are basically platform independent so I think this is fair assumption for programmers at stackoverflow.  Wow, great idea to check the API! Thanks for the example.

Comment: You can just access `https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>` from your browser and `Ctrl+F` "created_at".