# How to find the created date of a repository project on GitHub?

Tags: github

How can I find the created date of a project on GitHub?

Basically, I have to find the first commit to see the created date, however, some projects have 500 commits, which wastes a lot of time trying to get to the first commit page.

Is there a quicker way to get the created date?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a easy way on GitHub.com to find a repositories creation date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157557/is-there-a-easy-way-on-github-com-to-find-a-repositories-creation-date)

Answer (score 314, accepted):

> How can I find the created date of a project on GitHub?

Use the **[Repos GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get)** to retrieve this information

- **Syntax**: `https://api.github.com/repos/{:owner}/{:repository}`
- **Example:** `https://api.github.com/repos/libgit2/libgit2sharp`

The JSON payload will expose a `created_at` member with the UTC date the repository was created.

Considering the **[LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp)** repository above, one can see that it's been created on Feb, 2nd 2011 at 16:44:49 UTC.

**Note:** The `created_at` won't necessarily reflect the date of the first commit. It's the date the repository has been created on GitHub. For instance, the `xunit/resharper-xunit` project was recently **[moved from codeplex to GitHub](http://sticklebackplastic.com/post/2014/05/02/ReSharper-runner-for-xUnitnet-20.aspx)**. The `created_at` date is `2014-05-01T11:17:56Z`, but the most of the commits date back much more farther than that.

Comment: This is for a public repo, right? Any idea about private?

Comment: This worked on a live repo and also on a recently dead one too.

Comment: @kraftydevil Check this for private repositories.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611669/how-to-see-a-created-date-of-a-repository-project-on-github/#49097550

Comment: Handy cURL one-liner `curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/KhronosGroup/WebGL | grep 'created_at' | cut -d: -f2-`. Prints `"2016-03-11T02:02:33Z",` :)

Comment: @legends or someone else, suggestions for converting to human readable timestamps?

Comment: @jasonleonhard Looks like [it is in ISO 8601 time format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29281935/183120); the `Z` means it's in UTC0 time zone and `T` is just a separator. Perhaps you can do the conversion yourself?

Comment: @legends2k Thanks for the response. Just curious if there is some cli tool to convert it to human readable or perhaps an api flag.

Comment: For private repos you need a [Github Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens). Then use this token in the `Authorization` header of the request . Example with curl: `curl --header "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" 'https://api.github.com/repos/{:owner}/{:repository}`. You can also pipe that to `jq` and get only the creation date: `curl ... | jq .created_at`.

Answer (score 55):

If you are not interested in the exact creation date, and just would like to know how old a repo roughly is. You can go to `Insights`, then `Contributors`. For example, [first commit for `react` was pushed on `May 26 2013`](https://github.com/facebook/react/graphs/contributors).

Comment: I found that the section *code frequency* displays the same information.

Answer (score 40):

@nulltoken's answer is very useful. To make it even more convenient, I decided to create a [chrome extension](https://github.com/lvarayut/github-date-of-creation) for displaying a date of creation of a repository.

**Highlights**

- Beautiful calendar icon in the summary bar on a repository page
- Customizable date format followed Moment format pattern
- Best performance by storing all fetched URIs in the Storage

**Date of creation of a repository is displaying on the right side info area:**

[image: side info]

*OLD VIEW: Date of creation of a repository was displaying on the summary bar:*

[image: landpage]

**Date format is customizable by clicking at the extension icon:**

[image: option]

This's working really well for me. I hope it's useful for you as well.

Comment: @LVarayut That's a much better design than the one achieved by my UserJS script (see my answer).

Comment: Github changed the ui since then, so it looks a little different now - it's on the right side below the readme and license links

Comment: It's not even their ^ now... removed completely?

Comment: @PredragStojadinović Nice catch, I suggested an edit to add a screenshot with the new view, it's in review queue.

Answer (score 32):

I've written a bookmarklet for this, It may come in handy. You can even know the details of private or private - organization repositories with a simple workaround.

[GitHub repository size, creation date bookmarklet](https://www.syncwithtech.org/github-repos-size-creation-date/#bookmarklet) | [Source Code](https://github.com/vicke4/github-repo-info)

[image]

Answer (score 25):

**Syntax:**

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/{:owner}/{:repository} | jq '.created_at'
```

**Example:**

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/NabiKAZ/video2gif | jq '.created_at'
```

**Result:**

```
"2017-04-22T22:58:47Z"
```

Comment: This worked on a live repo, but not on a recently dead one. @nulltoken's answer worked on both. Not a criticism - just info.

Comment: For private repos, just pass in your github username with the curl command `-u {:username}`. You'll be prompted for your password.

Comment: If you do not have `jq` command then use `grep '.created_at'` instead.

Comment: @PéterSzilvási yes, but that return `"created_at": "2017-04-22T22:58:47Z",` no only date.

Comment: You can extract the date using the `cut` command: `echo '"created_at": "2017-04-22T22:58:47Z",' | cut -d "\"" -f 4`. At this point, I would prefer the `jq` command over `grep` plus `cut` command, since it is more readable.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use Github's new [GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/):

```
query { 
  repository(owner: "graphql", name: "graphql-js") {
    name
    createdAt
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's the answer without external plugins:

- Click on your Profile (top right) and select **Settings**
- In your **Settings** page, Click the **Security log** option in the Sidebar.
- You should able to see all your repositories on the right
- **Hover on the date** displayed to show the full date and time in a tooltip.

Comment: This is only helpful if you were the one that created the github repo.

Comment: I tried this. The security log just says "recent events" and has a search filter I can use to search through events.

Comment: It does not show the repositories on the right anymore. Furthermore it does not seem to have old data.

Answer (score 3):

For me I prefer this solution especially if you simply want to click things or stay in github

**Steps**

1. Go to your **repository**
2. View all the **commits**
3. Click on **All time** filter
4. From the filter, select the **oldest year** and **month**. Then select a range of about 1 week.
5. Look for your initial commit and check the date. You can hover on the commit time to see the date

That's it. Please check the images below for more info

**Step 2:**

[image: click commits]

**Step 3:**

[image: filters]

**Step 4:**

[image: filter github commits]

**Step 5:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I created a user script that shows the creation date directly on the GitHub page of the repo: https://openuserjs.org/scripts/cosenal/GitHub_Repo_Dates

Answer (score 2):

With `gh` installed it's just

```bash
gh api repos/{:owner}/{:repository} --jq '.created_at'
```

If you're authenticated, this also works for your private repositories.

The `gh` CLI also has some other nice commands. For example, you can get the created dates of all your repositories using

```bash
gh repo list -L 999 --json name,createdAt
```

where `-L` is some number larger than the amount of repositories you have.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a bash function for this.

```
# get github repo created time
ghage(){
  gh_url=${1:?usage: ghage https://github.com/owner/repo}
  owner_and_repo="$(echo "${gh_url}" | cut -d "/" -f4-5)"
  created_time=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/${owner_and_repo}" | jq -r '.created_at')
  echo "${created_time}"
}
```

Example:

```
$ ▶ ghage https://github.com/torvalds/linux
2011-09-04T22:48:12Z
```

Credit to nulltoken for the API info.

Answer (score 0):

Just look for the most likely files that would be created when the repo is initially setup such as gitignore or README.md. Then check their history. Normally these files will not have a lot of commits and you can easily check the commit history on those to find the oldest commit.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a C# version, you can run a unit test I wrote:

[https://github.com/nilnul/nilnul.fs.*git*.*TEST*/blob/nilnul-pub/svr_/github/client/repo/vw/UnitTest1.cs](https://github.com/nilnul/nilnul.fs._git_._TEST_/blob/nilnul-pub/svr_/github/client/repo/vw/UnitTest1.cs)

As the comment therein goes, you need to set your token in Windows Credential Manager, and also you need to create a dir named your username in the designated place. (For a pub repo, we shall not push your personal info.)