# How to get '2017-08-29T09:43:42.335Z' date format in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I get `2017-08-29T09:43:42.335Z` date format in PHP.
And what does `T09:43:42.335Z` correspond to?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us code

Comment: Have you tried to search a littl my friend?

Comment: It's a timestamp format. You can find the meaning of T & Z in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281935/what-exactly-does-the-t-and-z-mean-in-timestamp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T09:43:42.335Z` is the time (including milliseconds) in the Zulu timezone (the T is just a separator).

This is not a time format that's built-in in PHP. As of PHP 7.0.0 you could make it yourself like so:

```
$date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z');
```

In earlier PHP versions there is no "milliseconds" option, so you would have to concatenate that yourself.

The Zulu timezone is equal to UTC+0. Make sure you convert your time to UTC+0 before you print this out, the format command won't do that for you.