# How to convert the time 2020-09-25T00:20:00.000Z in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the time in the following format in my dataframe:

```
print(df)
            Date
    2020-09-25T00:20:00.000Z
```

Two questions:
a) What format is this?
b) how can I create a new column with the date and time in Australian time (AEDT).

Any help would be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What format is this?

Check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29281935):

> The T doesn't really stand for anything. It is just the separator that the ISO 8601 combined date-time format requires. You can read it as an abbreviation for Time.
> The Z stands for the Zero timezone, as it is offset by 0 from the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

How can I create a new column with the date and time in Australian time (AEDT)?

Convert column to datetimes and then use [`Series.dt.tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.tz_convert('Australia/Sydney')
print (df)
                       Date
0 2020-09-25 10:20:00+10:00
```

Comment: Ah great.Thanks @jezrael makes sense! Is there a way of removing the `+10:00` from the output or should i just remove the last 6 characters?

Comment: @SOK - If need remove timezone information use `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.tz_convert(None)`

Comment: Sorry - I would like it to be in the `Australia/Sydney` Timezone still but just would like it to show `2020-09-25 10:20:00` instead of `2020-09-25 10:20:00+10:00` if thats posible?

Comment: @SOK - df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.tz_convert('Australia/Sydney').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Comment: @SOK - If need timezones info then not