# How to parse LocalDateTime string with special pattern?

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I have String of time like: `2021-04-23T20:18:48.442826841Z` How can I parse it to [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)? Which [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) I need to specify?

Comment: There is a pretty good documentation available here https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: In which time zone do you want the resulting `LocalDateTime`? BTW don’t use `LocalDateTime` but `ZonedDateTime` for a date and time in a desired time zone.

Answer (score 2):

To begin, please read [What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime).

Referring to [What exactly does the T and Z mean in timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281935/what-exactly-does-the-t-and-z-mean-in-timestamp), the given string represent an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), and suppose you want a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) with system default timezone, you may parse as following.

```java
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.parse("2021-04-23T20:18:48.442826841Z"), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Or with [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT)

```java
LocalDateTime.parse("2021-04-23T20:18:48.442826841Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2021-04-23T20:18:48.442826841Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```

Works for me.

Comment: It gave me java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-04-23T20:18:48.442826841Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10.