# Pandas to_datetime adding T values in dateformat

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to convert a column "col1" to datetime format in a dataframe. "col1" has date values as strings with date format like "2021-10-01 00:00:00". The code I am using is:

`data['Output']=pd.to_datetime(data['col1'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

But while doing so, the date values in "Output" column are coming like this "2021-10-01T00:00:00.000000000". I don't know what is this T value in the date, and I don't want to have it in my data. I only want date and timestamp. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://akuiper.com/console/LT3-xUHeJCLg). Which pandas version are you using ?

Comment: What is T? => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281935/what-exactly-does-the-t-and-z-mean-in-timestamp/29282022

It is standard character and many language can parse this T fine, but if you want to remove it, as @Psidom said, let us know your env info.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "*the date values in "Output"*" - do you save the dataframe e.g. to a file?