# Typescript date not the same

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

I just want to know why these two dates in ISO format are not the same.

```js
const d1 = '2022-08-04T08:16:32.716904'
const d2 = '2022-08-04T08:16:32.716Z'

console.log(new Date(d1).toLocaleString())
// "04/08/2022, 08:16:32"
console.log(new Date(d2).toLocaleString())
// "04/08/2022, 10:16:32"
```

Answer (score 1):

> The Z stands for the Zero timezone, as it is offset by 0 from the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29282022/11659853

This means the two Date objects have different time zones. The other Date object probably has your local time zone.

Answer (score 0):

The timezone of of `d1` is not the same of the timezone of `d2`.
`d2` is in Zulu (UTC) while `d1` is given in your local timezone since the timezone info was not provided in the datestring.

Notice `d2` has a `Z` letter after the time. `d1` misses this.

You can look up more info about ISO datestrings and their timezone offset here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601