# Converting date to UTC with Laravel function

Tags: php, laravel, timezone, php-carbon

I'm trying to convert an incoming date with a specific timezone to UTC. My code looks like this (please see comments for date/timezone):

```
convertToUTC(
    $request->scheduled_at, //2023-05-13T12:00:00.000Z
    $request->user()->company->timezone, //Europe/Amsterdam
); 

function convertToUTC($timestamp, $timezone)
{
    $carbon = new \Carbon\Carbon($timestamp, $timezone);

    $carbon->setTimezone('UTC');

    $utcTimestamp = $carbon->toDateTimeString();

    return $utcTimestamp;
}|
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
2023-05-13T10:00:00.000Z
```

Because Amsterdam is 2 hours behind UTC. However, I keep receiving `2023-05-13T12:00:00.000Z`(no change). Why is it not converted correctly to utc?

Comment: `Z` sets the timezone to UTC

Comment: `2023-05-13T12:00:00.000Z` is already in UTC. Your front-end code is already sending a UTC ("Zulu time") value that doesn't require conversion.

Comment: Either that, or your frontend code is sending date/time strings with the incorrect time/timezone.

Comment: Thanks! Frontend is indeed the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Z at end of timestamp means Zero Timezone (Zulu Time Zone) as it offset by 0 from UTC for detailed explanation you can see this thread on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281935/what-exactly-does-the-t-and-z-mean-in-timestamp).
and [here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones) list of military time zones that contains explanation for every letter.
You can also use B at the end for +2hr offset as listed in list of timezones.