# How to find the "going public" date of a repository project on GitHub?

Tags: github

First, my assumptions:

1. A project can first be created on a private Github repo & then made it public at a later date
2. If using the answer from "[How to find the created date of a repository project on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611669/how-to-find-the-created-date-of-a-repository-project-on-github)", it will not give me the "going public" date but only the creation date

So, is there any way to find out that "going public" date?

Answer (score 1):

(Note: I know I'm pretty late but this is for anyone who's got the same query.)

If you are logged into GitHub, you will get all information regarding changes on repositories and your profile in the [Security Log](https://github.com/settings/security-log). You can further filter out other info to obtain the [Repository management](https://github.com/settings/security-log?q=action%3Arepo.create%20action%3Arepo.destroy%20action%3Arepo.access) logs. The "going public" date will be visible when you hover over the ' ago' info on the bottom right of your relevant log.

Here's an example:
[image: GH Example]
You have to hover over the section marked in yellow and pointed at by the yellow arrow.

Comment: Yea but how can someone see/verify it for a public (not yours) repo?